# css fontawesome icon align with two text line inside a button ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to align a fontawesome icon with two lines where the icon is on the same row as the first sentence.

Here is the desire render

{icon} This is the first sentence
       This is the second sentence

However, I got this 
       This is the second sentence
{icon} This is the sentence sentence

My JSX code

```
<Button className{myStyle.iconButton}>
  <i className="fa fa-user"/>
  <p className={myStyle.iconText}>
    {"This is the first sentence"}<br/>
    {"This is the second sentence"}
  </p>
</Button>

.CSS

.iconButton
  text-align: left

.iconText
  display: inline-block
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the iconButton class a flex box

```
.iconButton{
display: flex;
align-items: baseline;
}
```